# Find spectators that have seen the same shows (match multiple rows for each)

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, relational-division

For an assignment I have to write several SQL queries for a database stored in a PostgreSQL server running PostgreSQL 9.3.0. However, I find myself blocked with last query. The database models a reservation system for an opera house. The query is about associating the a spectator the other spectators that assist to the same events every time.

The model looks like this:

```
Reservations table 
id_res |     create_date     |  tickets_presented  | id_show | id_spectator | price | category 
-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+-------+----------
     1 | 2015-08-05 17:45:03 |                     |       1 |            1 |   195 |        1
     2 | 2014-03-15 14:51:08 | 2014-11-30 14:17:00 |      11 |            1 |   150 |        2

Spectators table

id_spectator   | last_name  | first_name |                email                   |     create_time     | age 
---------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+-----   
             1 | gonzalez   | colin      | colin.gonzalez@gmail.com               | 2014-03-15 14:21:30 |  22
             2 | bequet     | camille    | bequet.camille@gmail.com               | 2014-12-10 15:22:31 |  22

Shows table
 id_show |          name          |  kind  | presentation_date | start_time | end_time | id_season | capacity_cat1 | capacity_cat2 | capacity_cat3 | price_cat1 | price_cat2 | price_cat3 
---------+------------------------+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+------------
       1 | madama butterfly       | opera  | 2015-09-05        | 19:30:00   | 21:30:00 |         2 |           315 |           630 |           945 |        195 |        150 |        100
       2 | don giovanni           | opera  | 2015-09-12        | 19:30:00   | 21:45:00 |         2 |           315 |           630 |           945 |        195 |        150 |        100
```

So far I've started by writing a query to get the id of the spectator and the date of the show he's attending to, the query looks like this.

```
SELECT Reservations.id_spectator, Shows.presentation_date
FROM Reservations
LEFT JOIN Shows ON Reservations.id_show = Shows.id_show;
```

Could someone help me understand better the problem and hint me towards finding a solution. Thanks in advance.

So the result I'm expecting should be something like this

```
id_spectator | other_id_spectators
-------------+--------------------
            1|                 2,3
```

Meaning that every time spectator with id 1 went to a show, spectators 2 and 3 did too.

Comment: Here is a hint -- you only need to select from one table.

Comment: @Hogan could you be at least be a little more specific.

Comment: Really?  You can't figure out which table?  There are only 3.   Which table has ids of spectators and shows?

Comment: @Hogan, ok yes I figured we can get the id_spectators and id_shows from the Reservations table but I can't understand how would it lead me to the final answer.

Comment: I have a policy not to answer a question which is tagged with more than one platform since sql can vary between platforms I'm certain to not know what code the user needs which are you using sql-server or postgresql?

Comment: @Hogan, I miss-tagged sql-server, I'm using PostgreSQL only as pointed out in the beginning of the post.

Comment: Why is this tagged "SQL-Server" if you using Postgres? And what is your version of Postgres (always provide this). Click edit (left under your question) to improve your question.

Comment: psql  (PostgreSQL) 9.3.0

Comment: psql is the name of the client program and its version does not have to be the same as the server - `SELECT version()`.

Comment: there you go it's been corrected @Erwin

Comment: Here is hint number 2 -- with this version you can use `STRING_AGG`

Comment: The expected result contradicts the demo data. There is no spectator 3 and the only reservations made so far are for spectator 1. This should really make sense *together* to be of use to the general public. Also; you did not properly define what you are looking for. AFAIU, this is a problem of "relational division" and is not as trivial as some comments would have you believe.

Comment: @Erwin, I understand what you're. I only printed the first two lines of  the the tables that's why there's missing data. I didn't want to make a long post, and I believed that the example I gave for the expected result was enough to really understand the point of the query, because I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, the rules aren't very clear, so I can't be very clear either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Meaning that every time spectator with id 1 went to a show, spectators 2 and 3 did too.

In other words, you want a list of ...
*all spectators that have seen all the shows that a given spectator has seen (and possibly more than the given one)*

This is a special case of **relational division**. We have assembled an arsenal of basic techniques here:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

It is special because the list of shows each spectator has to have attended is dynamically determined by the given prime spectator.

Assuming that `(d_spectator, id_show)` is unique in `reservations`, which has not been clarified.

A `UNIQUE` constraint on those two columns (in that order) also provides the most important index.
For best performance in query 2 and 3 below also create an index with leading `id_show`.

#### 1. Brute force

The primitive approach would be to form a sorted array of shows the given user has seen and compare the same array of others:

```
SELECT 1 AS id_spectator, array_agg(sub.id_spectator) AS id_other_spectators
FROM  (
   SELECT id_spectator
   FROM   reservations r
   WHERE  id_spectator <> 1
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING        array_agg(id_show ORDER BY id_show)
      @> (SELECT array_agg(id_show ORDER BY id_show)
          FROM   reservations
          WHERE  id_spectator = 1)
   ) sub;
```

But this is potentially **very expensive** for big tables. The whole table hast to be processes, and in a rather expensive way, too.

#### 2. Smarter

Use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to determine relevant shows, then only consider those

```
WITH shows AS (             -- all shows of id 1; 1 row per show
   SELECT id_spectator, id_show
   FROM   reservations
   WHERE  id_spectator = 1  -- your prime spectator here
   )
SELECT sub.id_spectator, array_agg(sub.other) AS id_other_spectators
FROM  (
   SELECT s.id_spectator, r.id_spectator AS other
   FROM   shows s
   JOIN   reservations r USING (id_show)
   WHERE  r.id_spectator <> s.id_spectator
   GROUP  BY 1,2
   HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM shows)
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[`@>` is the "contains2 operator for arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) - so we get all spectators that have *at least* seen the same shows.

Faster than *1.* because only relevant shows are considered.

#### 3. Real smart

To also exclude spectators that are not going to qualify early from the query, use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE shows AS (   -- produces exactly 1 row
   SELECT id_spectator, array_agg(id_show) AS shows, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   reservations
   WHERE  id_spectator = 1  -- your prime spectator here
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
, cte AS (
   SELECT r.id_spectator, 1 AS idx
   FROM   shows s
   JOIN   reservations r ON r.id_show = s.shows[1]
   WHERE  r.id_spectator <> s.id_spectator

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT r.id_spectator, idx + 1
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   reservations r USING (id_spectator)
   JOIN   shows s ON s.shows[c.idx + 1] = r.id_show
   )
SELECT s.id_spectator, array_agg(c.id_spectator) AS id_other_spectators
FROM   shows s
JOIN   cte c ON c.idx = s.ct  -- has an entry for every show
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Note that the first CTE is *non-recursive*. Only the second part is recursive (iterative really).

This should be **fastest for small selections from big tables**. Row that don't qualify are excluded early. the two indices I mentioned are essential.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5955f/20) demonstrating all three.

Comment: @ErwinBrandsetter Oh and you're right (id_spectator, id_show) is unique in each reservation

Answer (score 3):

**Note based on comments**: Wanted to make clear that this answer may be of limited use as it was answered in the context of SQL-Server (tag was present at the time)

There is probably a better way to do it, but you could do it with the 'stuff 'function. The only drawback here is that, since your ids are ints, placing a comma between values will involve a work around (would need to be a string). Below is the method I can think of using a work around.

```
SELECT [id_spectator], [id_show]
, STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(A.[id_spectator] as NVARCHAR(10))
FROM reservations A
Where A.[id_show]=B.[id_show] AND a.[id_spectator] != b.[id_spectator] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As [other_id_spectators]
From reservations B
Group By [id_spectator], [id_show]
```

This will show you all other spectators that attended the same shows.

Comment: After thinking this through, making a temporary tables wasn't needed. could just use the cast function, updated accordingly.

Comment: I thought of it, I'm trying your proposition, seems to do the work. Thanks!

Comment: So instead I can use the string agg function

Comment: This is not even close to anything that would work in Postgres. `stuff` is not valid in Postgres, neither is `XML PATH` or the non-standard square brackets instead of standard double quotes etc. What's more, it's not working in SQL Server either: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33dc7/1

Comment: When the question was posted it had a sql tag so it was answered in that manner. I ran the queries in actual SQL after staging data and it worked, I did use not sql fiddle. Have you tried running it in sql? Is it possible that there is a discrepancy in sqlfiddle vs MS SQL?

Comment: @JMariña: My link is to an sqlfiddle for *SQL Server*: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33dc7/1. And there is still an SQL tag. You seem to be under the impression that SQL would be connected to MS SQL Server?

Comment: But you are right, there was an "SQL Server" tag. So I removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have one half of the total question--determining which id_shows a particular id_spectator attended.

What you want to ask yourself is how you can determine which id_spectators attended an id_show, given an id_show. Once you have that, combine the two answers to get the full result.

Comment: I don't think this is very helpful since this is still only describes about half the solution

Answer (score 0):

So the final answer I got, looks like this :

```
SELECT id_spectator, id_show,(
    SELECT string_agg(to_char(A.id_spectator, '999'), ',')
    FROM Reservations A
    WHERE A.id_show=B.id_show
) AS other_id_spectators
FROM Reservations B
GROUP By id_spectator, id_show
ORDER BY id_spectator ASC;
```

Which prints something like this:

```
id_spectator | id_show | other_id_spectators 
-------------+---------+---------------------
           1 |       1 |    1,   2,   9
           1 |      14 |    1,   2
```

Which suits my needs, however if you have any improvements to offer, please share :) Thanks again everybody!